# Get raw HTTP response from AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Using plain JavaScript AJAX in a browser, can I get the *raw* HTTP response from the server?

By that I mean headers and body as raw text like:

```
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://www.google.co.uk/
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Server: gws
< Content-Length: 221
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Age: 11
< Date: Mon, 04 Jun 2018 09:12:14 GMT
< Expires: Wed, 04 Jul 2018 09:12:14 GMT
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.uk/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

(NB: I'm not talking about cross-origin requests)

Comment: Browser or something like Node?

Comment: Please don't forget to show us your attempts so far.

Comment: @Lloyd browser, updated

Comment: `getAllResponseHeaders` should get you access to every response header but the actual status code line, and the body you have access to directly anyhow.

Comment: I think the closest you can get is the `XMLHttpRequest` object's `.getAllResponseHeaders()` output, but that will have already been normalised by the browser, so it's not completely raw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to combine two calls to get the body and the response headers.

- To get the headers, use [`getAllResponseHeaders`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getAllResponseHeaders)
- To get the body, use property [`.response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response) when the readystate is 4 (=DONE)

---

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://www.example.com", true);
request.send(null);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (request.readyState == 4){
    console.log(request.getAllResponseHeaders());
    console.log(request.responseText);
  }
};
```

Comment: In these cases it is not the raw response though? They've each been processed by the browser. Could be what I'm asking for is not possible.

Comment: Checking the docs of `getAllResponseHeaders` it states it fetches the raw header string. Also, checking the example in the `.response` docs it states **The content is handled as raw text data** in case of using default responseType.