# How to get raw HttpResponse using Hyper or Reqwest?

Tags: post, rust, get, hyper, reqwest

Is there a way to get the actual/original/raw http response after doing a `reqwest::get("https://httpbin.org/ip").send().await?`

or from hyper : `client.get("https://httpbin.org/ip".parse()?).await?`

I need a similar result to what postman returns:

```
Date: Mon, 13 Jul 2020 07:43:46 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 33
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
{
  "origin": "102.200.212.40"
}
```

Somehow reqwest organizes the response too well; into `version()`, `status()`, `headers()` etc.

The reason why I specifically mentioned reqwest and/or hyper, is because these are being used extensively all around the code. I'm hoping that I could still use them, before we try another crate/lib.

Comment: what wrong with https://docs.rs/http/0.2.1/http/request/struct.Request.html#method.headers ?

Comment: hi @Stargateur

i actually need the size of the raw response; and not just the headers only, :(

Comment: I don't think hyper and request can do that, also, this is a really strange request

Comment: @Stargateur, not sure if what you find strange is the question to get a raw http response...?

Comment: both are strange

Comment: hi @Stargateur, i'm saddened that you find it strange. :( 
this question is kinda asked in java, ajax too:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282889/get-raw-http-response-with-retrofit],
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50677103/get-raw-http-response-from-ajax]

so i thought it wouldn't be any different if I ask a rust equivalent to a similar question.

I am just hoping I could do it in reqwest or hyper, since I'm very new to Rust.

Comment: This isn't a strange request at all, I'm also stuck looking for raw headers.  Just because the problems you happen to solve don't need raw headers doesn't mean that there are no valid use cases for access to raw headers.  Bummed that reqwest has this limitation that for me severely limits its usefulness.

Answer (score -2):

@B.CarlaYap acttually your question is not understandable.. can you update and add an exact display of Postman call you are making. as well you are looking at HEADER which you could get from Response.

you could use Blocking which is simpler to understand.

```
reqwest = {version = "0.10.8", features = ["blocking", "json"]}
```

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {

    println!("GET https://www.rust-lang.org");

    let mut res = reqwest::blocking::get("https://www.rust-lang.org/")?;

    println!("Status: {}", res.status());
    println!("Headers:\n{:?}", res.headers());

    // copy the response body directly to stdout
    res.copy_to(&mut std::io::stdout())?;

    println!("\n\nDone.");
    Ok(())
}
```